# SVG text color with correspond to background

Tags: html, css, svg, d3.js

I am using D3.js to make a graph like on this image:

[image]

Generally, all works fine, but I don't know how to make the labels visible when the bar doesn't cover all of it. My first idea was to add two labels. One with white color and another with bar color. I hoped that some magic could happen and text outside of the bar would be green, which did not work.

Here is the piece of code that i use to add labels:

```
var rect = this.svg.selectAll("text")
                .data(dataset, dataset.key)
                .enter();

rect.append("text")
  .text(function(d) { return d.value; })
  .attr("text-anchor", "end")
  .attr("x", w-10) 
  .attr("y", function(d, i) { return graph.xScale(i) + graph.xScale(1)/2; })
  .attr("fill", color)
  .attr("class", "value");

rect.append("text")
  .text(function(d) { return d.key; })
  .attr("text-anchor", "start")
  .attr("x", 10) 
  .attr("y", function(d, i) { return graph.xScale(i) + graph.xScale(1)/2; })
  .attr("fill", color)
  .attr("class", "key");

rect.append("text")
  .text(function(d) { return d.key; })
  .attr("text-anchor", "start")
  .attr("x", 10) 
  .attr("y", function(d, i) { return graph.xScale(i) + graph.xScale(1)/2; })
  .attr("fill", textColor)
  .attr("class", "keybg");
```

How to achieve such effect?

Comment: I guess there is no CSS to invert the color of the part of the text, which  sticks out from the rect. Maybe you want to change the colors in a way, that the text is readable on both the bar color and background color. Or detect a label that sticks out and move it completely outside and give it another color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach to use clip paths has already been described by squeamish ossifrage's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29276302/4235784). I have put together a working snippet doing it the d3 way:

```js
var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr({
        width: 400,
        height: 400
    });

var textOut = svg.append("text")
    .attr({
        x: 120,
        y: 66
    })
    .style({
        fill: "black",
        stroke: "none"
    })
    .text("Description");

var rect = svg.append("rect")
                    .attr({
                        id: "rect",
                        x: 50,
                        y: 50,
                        width: 100,
                        height: 20
                    })
                    .style({
                        fill: "limegreen",
                        stroke: "darkgreen"
                    });

svg.append("clipPath")
    .attr("id", "clip")
    .append("use")
    .attr("xlink:href", "#rect");

var textIn = svg.append("text")
    .attr({
        x: 120,
        y: 66
    })
    .style({
        fill: "white",
        stroke: "none",
        "clip-path": "url(#clip)"
    })
    .text("Description");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

I've further shortened things by not setting up `clipPath`s in the `defs` section but instead linking to the `rect` which has already been drawn via `xlink:href`:

```
svg.append("clipPath")
    .attr("id", "clip")
    .append("use")
    .attr("xlink:href", "#rect");
```

This will result in an svg structure like the following:

```svg
  <text x="120" y="66" style="fill: rgb(0, 0, 0); stroke: none;">Description</text>
  <rect id="rect" x="50" y="50" width="100" height="20" style="fill: rgb(50, 205, 50); stroke: rgb(0, 100, 0);"/>
  <clipPath id="clip">
    <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#rect"/>
  </clipPath>
  <text x="120" y="66" style="fill: rgb(255, 255, 255); stroke: none; clip-path: url(#clip);">Description</text>
```

Comment: Thank both of you that is very helpful. I hope last question how this clipPath-> use xlink:href will act when i will dynamically change the width of rect?

Comment: The `xlink:href` is a live link adjusting the clip path whenever the `rect`is resized. Try adding `rect.transition().attr({ width: 20 }).transition().attr({ width: 100 });` to the end of the snippet to see an animation of the rect.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done quite easily with clipping masks. Here's a static SVG to illustrate the point:

```html
<svg width="400" height="200" viewBox="0 0 400 200">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clip_1">
      <rect width="50" height="38" />
    </clipPath>
    <clipPath id="clip_2">
      <rect width="100" height="38" />
    </clipPath>
    <clipPath id="clip_3">
      <rect width="150" height="38" />
    </clipPath>
    <clipPath id="clip_4">
      <rect width="250" height="38" />
    </clipPath>
    <clipPath id="clip_5">
      <rect width="300" height="38" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <rect width="400" height="200" fill="white" path="none" />
  <g transform="translate(0,1)">
    <text x="10" y="28" font-family="Verdana" font-size="20" fill="red">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</text>
    <g clip-path="url(#clip_1)">
      <rect width="50" height="38" fill="red" />
      <text x="10" y="28" font-family="Verdana" font-size="20" fill="white">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</text>
    </g>
  </g>
  <g transform="translate(0,41)">
    <text x="10" y="28" font-family="Verdana" font-size="20" fill="orange">Consectetur adipiscing elit</text>
    <g clip-path="url(#clip_2)">
      <rect width="100" height="38" fill="orange" />
      <text x="10" y="28" font-family="Verdana" font-size="20" fill="white">Consectetur adipiscing elit</text>
    </g>
  </g>
  <g transform="translate(0,81)">
    <text x="10" y="28" font-family="Verdana" font-size="20" fill="green">Proin egestas suscipit justo</text>
    <g clip-path="url(#clip_3)">
      <rect width="150" height="38" fill="green" />
      <text x="10" y="28" font-family="Verdana" font-size="20" fill="white">Proin egestas suscipit justo</text>
    </g>
  </g>
  <g transform="translate(0,121)">
    <text x="10" y="28" font-family="Verdana" font-size="20" fill="blue">Nam eget magna gravida eros</text>
    <g clip-path="url(#clip_4)">
      <rect width="250" height="38" fill="blue" />
      <text x="10" y="28" font-family="Verdana" font-size="20" fill="white">Nam eget magna gravida eros</text>
    </g>
  </g>
  <g transform="translate(0,161)">
    <text x="10" y="28" font-family="Verdana" font-size="20" fill="purple">Accumsan tempor eget sed augue</text>
    <g clip-path="url(#clip_5)">
      <rect width="300" height="38" fill="purple" />
      <text x="10" y="28" font-family="Verdana" font-size="20" fill="white">Accumsan tempor eget sed augue</text>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Basically what you need to do is draw every text segment in two different colours, and use clipping masks to reveal the text that sits on the background. So for example, the first bar in this example is created as follows:

1: Define a clip path that exactly matches the shape of the foreground object:

```html
<defs>
  <clipPath id="clip_1">
    <rect width="50" height="38" />
  </clipPath>
  <!-- more paths here -->
</defs>
```

2: Draw the text to be viewed against the background colour:

```html
<text x="10" y="28" font-family="Verdana" font-size="20" fill="red">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</text>
```

3: Create a group containing the foreground object and text using the same coordinates as the clip path and background text, and include a `clip-path` parameter to crop the text where it extends beyond the foreground object:

```html
<g clip-path="url(#clip_1)">
  <rect width="50" height="38" fill="red" />
  <text x="10" y="28" font-family="Verdana" font-size="20" fill="white">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</text>
</g>
```

It shouldn't be too hard to integrate this into your D3 code.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, this can be done using CSS only. There is a CSS property named [`mix-blend-mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode), which

> ...describes how an element's content should blend with the content of the element's direct parent and the element's background.

So, it's just a matter of setting it in the CSS:

```
yourSelector {
    mix-blend-mode: someValue;
}
```

This is a demo:

```css
text {
 mix-blend-mode: difference;
}
```

```html
<svg width="400" heigth="200">
 <rect x="10" y="10" height="30" width="350" fill="green"></rect>
 <rect x="10" y="50" height="30" width="150" fill="green"></rect>
 <rect x="10" y="90" height="30" width="50" fill="green"></rect>
 <text x="20" y="30" fill="white">I am a very very very very long long long long long text</text>
 <text x="20" y="70" fill="white">I am a very very very very long long long long long text</text>
 <text x="20" y="110" fill="white">I am a very very very very long long long long long text</text>
</svg>
```

There are two problems: you cannot control the colours precisely, and it is not supported by IE/Edge.