# Change text color depending on background using D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, colors, background-color

I created a simple bar chart using D3,js and faced a problem with text color.
When text is inside the bar it looks pretty well, but if the text is too long it become unreadable.
[image]
How can I change text color depending on red rect width(if text is inside the rect - default color otherwise - other color and make it works in Chrome/FF/IE11/Edge if this possible?

Appending text to the bar:

```
 bar.append("text")
  .attr('class', 'x-name-text')
  .attr("x", 10)
  .attr("y", barHeight / 2)
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .text(function(d) {
      return d.name;
  });
```

[jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/q1uc5vy0/3/)

**UPDATE:**
Possible solution for this:
1) append underlayer `text`:

```
 bar.append("text")
  .attr('class', 'x-name-text')
  .attr("x", 10)
  .attr("y", barHeight / 2)
  .attr("fill", "red")
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .text(function(d) {
      return d.name;
  });
```

2) append `rect`: (don't forget about unique `id` for each `rect`)

```
 bar.append("rect")
  .attr("fill", color(0))
  .attr("id", function(d) {
    return d.id;
 })
 ...
```

3) append `clipPath` and link it with `xlink:href` to necessary `rect` using the same `id`:

```
 // clipPath depending on rect width
 bar.append('clipPath')
   .attr('id', function(listItem, index) {
     return listItem.id + '' + index;
   })
   .append('use')
   .attr('xlink:href', function(listItem){
     return '#' + listItem.id;
   });
```

4) append the overlayer `text` with `clip-path` style propery that linked to id of `clipPath` SVG element:

```
 bar.append('text')
  .attr("x", 10)
  .attr("y", barHeight / 2)
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .attr('class', 'overflow-name')
  .style('clip-path', function(listItem, index) {
      return 'url(#' + listItem.id + '' + index + ')';
  })
  .text(function(d) {
      return d.name;
  });
```

[Working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/q1uc5vy0/7/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SVG text color with correspond to background](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29273237/svg-text-color-with-correspond-to-background)

Answer (score 2):

There are different ways to solve this. One of them is using CSS `mix-blend-mode`;

```
.chart .x-name-text {
    text-anchor: start;
    mix-blend-mode: difference;
}
```

Here is your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nmmgLe95/

And here you have a list with different options for `mix-blend-mode`: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode

Comment: Thank you. But IE11/Edge does not support it and even I can't control text colors setting this property. Is other way to solve this problem exists?

Comment: Indeed, IE doesn't support it (as thousands of other things it doesn't support...).

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Again, a nice answer of yours! However, I marked this question as duplicate and, to not loose this valuable information, would like to ask you to also post this answer to the older question. Please, consider adding a IE compatibility note.