# Image on top of text changing it's color

Tags: html, css, svg, sass, frontend

I'm trying to find out how to build something like this ([see attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNbGf.png)).
I do not know how to when a image (assuming it's an svg) goes on top of a H1 or any text it changes the text color.
The attachment i print here has a breathing effect on the blob, i wont have that but still it would be great to know.
Thank you.
[BlobText](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNbGf.png)

Comment: Does [SVG text color with correspond to background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29273237/svg-text-color-with-correspond-to-background) help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SVG text color with correspond to background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29273237/svg-text-color-with-correspond-to-background)